# Disable users from changing email address in buddypress

Tags: wordpress

I wish to disable users from changing their email address so only admin can do it.
one way was to delete the lines from general.php however when updating the theme this will cause issues and come back. i need a code to enter into my child theme functions.php

```
<label for=”email”><?php _e( ‘Account Email’, ‘buddypress’ ); ?></label>
<input type=”email” name=”email” id=”email” value=”<?php echo bp_get_displayed_user_email(); ?>” class=”settings-input” <?php bp_form_field_attributes( ’email’ ); ?>/>
```

This is the field i want to make read only/disable. i can add readonly to the code above but i need something to add to my child theme functions.php

thank you

i tried changing code but goes to original when updating theme

Comment: Create a child theme and overload general.php in that theme. https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#how-is-this-useful

Comment: Or write a small plugin: https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/template-overload-from-a-plugin/